# Sharepoint 2010 : Missing quicklaunch and ribbon after copy of wiki pages from one website to another via CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a problem to replicate my wiki pages from one SharePoint site to another one. I am using CSOM (Client Side Object Model) and the following (simplified) code :

```
                var fileCreationInformation = new SP.FileCreationInformation();

                string page = EXTRACTED VALUE OF THE SOURCE FIELD "wikiField" (string)
                byte[] bytes = new byte[page.Length * sizeof(char)];
                System.Buffer.BlockCopy(page.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                fileCreationInformation.Content = bytes;
                fileCreationInformation.Overwrite = true;
                fileCreationInformation.Url = EXTRACTED VALUE OF THE SOURCE FIELD "FileLeafRef" (string)

                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = oList.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInformation);
                clientContext.Load(uploadFile);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

My problem is after the copy, my new wiki pages are created and the content is perfectly displayed except that there is no Quicklaunch and Ribbon. It is just my raw content (e.g. XML only for xml page) which is displayed and it is kind of ugly :)

Do you have an idea how can I fix this issue? Do I miss something or I attack the problem in a wrong way?

Thank you in advance!

Nicolas

Comment: I expect that you are just making a file and that SharePoint doesn't know that you are wanting to create a file of type wiki page.  I will try to research this some more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Josh, it was the good idea. I fixed my problem by using the AddTemplateFile!
Here is the (simplified) code :

```
                string path = PATH
                SP.File wikiPage = oList.RootFolder.Files.AddTemplateFile(path, SP.TemplateFileType.WikiPage);
                wikiPage.ListItemAllFields["WikiField"] = CONTENT
                wikiPage.ListItemAllFields.Update();
```